# how to cut string from behind when hit / vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, trim

I have String:

`Dim Location As String = "D:/Temp/Stats.pdf"`

and I want to cut everything from right to left when I hit "/"
Output should be:

Stats.pdf

I tried `Sub.string` and `trimm`, but no luck, is it even possible to cut from behinde?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `String.Split` and `String().Last()`

```
Dim Location As String = "D:/Temp/Stats.pdf"
Dim Strs As String() = Location.Split("/")
Dim FileName As String = Strs.Last()
```

Your result is in the `FileName`

Comment: Thank you very much, this so easy, and i'm so angry on myself... :(

Comment: @LazaBre no, no, please take it easy. :) just learn one thing at a time, all right?

Comment: Ofc, thank you, i'm tring to learn vb.net language myself with online tutorials.. :P It's not easy like people say.. :P Thank you again

Comment: @LazaBre no problem... and all the best for your learning! :)

Comment: @LazeBre - Better to use `Path.GetFileName(Location)` as help-info.de says below

Comment: @ChrisDunaway that seems to be more "official" solution. Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You maybe interested in another code for other use cases:

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sLocation As String = "D:/Temp/Stats.pdf"
    Dim directoryPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(sLocation)
    Dim FileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sLocation)
    MessageBox.Show(directoryPath)
    MessageBox.Show(FileName)
  End Sub
End Class
```